# If the volume of a cylinder is fixed, derive the radius and height that will maximize the surface area

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

I know how to find the radius and height for minimum surface area. [https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/maximum-surface-area-of-cylinder.332279/ ].
For it to be minimum, h=r/2.
It would be great if someone could tell me how to find the values for maximum value.

Comment: First, you have to make sure that such a maximum exists.

Comment: How to prove so? @Peter

Comment: Here, we do not have a maximum. In general, it is enough to bound the possible values (as long as you have a continous function, minima and maxima must then exist)

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no maximal surface area.

To see that, start with an arbitary cylinder with the given volume.

Then, divide the height by $4$ and double the radius. The volume does not
change, but the area of the circle is $4$ times larger.

You can repeat this process as often as you want. It is clear that there
is no upper bound for the surface area.